# VS Code: What is the difference in settings between User and Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know what is the difference between changing `Visual Studio Code` settings in the `User` and the `Workspace` tab.

Comment: `User` settings apply to all workspaces, `Workspace` override `User` settings for this workspace, The same rules for `Folder` settings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [vscode settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

> VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:
>
> - User Settings - Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.
> - Workspace Settings - Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.
>
> Workspace settings override user settings. Workspace settings are
> specific to a project and can be shared across developers on a
> project.
>
> **Note**: A VS Code "workspace" is usually just your project root folder.
> Workspace settings as well as debugging and task configurations are
> stored at the root in a `.vscode` folder. You can also have more than
> one root folder in a VS Code workspace through a feature called
> [Multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces). You can learn more in the [What is a VS Code
> "workspace"?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces) article.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand Visual Studio Code's settings